# Get Average for a Date Range Relative to Each Row Using Postgres Window Functions

Tags: postgresql

**PROBLEM** Need to calculate average value over last 12 months for each row, using PostgreSQL 9.4 window functions (without GROUP BY).

Example:

```
MY_DATE     VALUE   NEW_VALUE  REGION_ID
2016-09-01  11                 1
2016-10-01  22                 1
2016-11-01  33                 1
2016-12-01  44                 1    
2017-01-01  55                 1    
2017-02-01  66                 1    
2017-03-01  77                 1    
2017-04-01  88                 1    
2017-05-01  99                 1    
2017-06-01  11                 1    
2017-07-01  22                 1    
2017-08-01  33      46.75      1
2017-09-01  44      49.5       1
2017-10-01  55      52.25      1
```

**RESEARCH** I get the AVG value, but for exact dates only:

```
-- Works, but for exact dates:

SELECT *, AVG(value) FILTER (
WHERE my_date > '2016-09-01'
  AND my_date < '2017-10-01') OVER (PARTITION BY region_id)
FROM my_table;

-- Precalculating extra field period_start_date = my_date - INTERVAL '12 month' doesn't work as expected:

SELECT *, AVG(value) FILTER (
WHERE my_date > period_start_date
  AND my_date < period_start_date + INTERVAL '12 MONTH') OVER (PARTITION BY region_id)
FROM my_table;
```

**QUESTION**
How to get the expected Select-result? Several queries allowed, but without procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT avg(t2.value)
               FROM my_table t2
               WHERE t2.region_id = t1.region_id
                     AND t2.my_date <= t1.my_date
                     AND t2.my_date > t1.my_date - '1 year'::interval)
       FROM my_table t1;
```

Comment: Works fine in version 9.4. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ad8980679d620c9995b99545541b2b55)

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN my_date >= '2017-08-01' THEN
        AVG(value) OVER (
            PARTITION BY region_id 
            ORDER BY my_date 
            -- 11 preceding months + current one == 12 months
            RANGE BETWEEN interval '11 months' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    ELSE NULL END
FROM mytable
```

**PostgreSQL 11** adds the support for `RANGE` intervals within window functions. This feature is exactly made for problems like this. [Further reading](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the project is on Postgres 9.4.

Comment: Is the number of records fixed to 12 each year? In this case we can change `RANGE BETWEEN interval` into `ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Comment: Shift to 12 month is irrelative to year. It is relative the current row. But there's no RANGE BETWEEN in PostreSQL 9.4. The https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit answer works at 9.4.

Comment: Yes, the RANGE feature does not exist, but the ROWS feature. ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=75a2858c3043440a3e9e8ed624b37ad1 But this only works if there exactly 12 records per year ;) But nevermind, the other solution is better anyway on yout case